# SQL Query to loop through AD OUs and get a count of objects

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

I'm trying to produce a report that has a count of computer objects within many, many AD OUs from SQL Server so I can join it to other data in a SQL DB and then create a report with SSRS.

I've figured out how to do it with a single OU (which represents a physical site location with a unique code in my situation) but I need to be able to do it for all the OUs in the directory.

This is my query to get the result for 1 single OU. Any ideas?

```
            DECLARE @SiteCode int
            SET @SiteCode = 1234

            DECLARE @Region nvarchar(100)
            SET @Region = (
                            SELECT TOP 1        RegionName
                            FROM            tbl_ADSiteInfo
                            WHERE           SiteCode = @SiteCode
                          )

            DECLARE @SiteName nvarchar(250)
            SET @SiteName = (
                                    SELECT TOP 1    SiteName
                                    FROM            tbl_ADSiteInfo
                                    WHERE           SiteCode = @SiteCode
                              )

            DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000)
            SET @SQL = '
            SELECT TOP 901  COUNT(*) As ''Count''
            FROM            OpenQuery(
                                        ADSI,
                                        ''
                                        SELECT distinguishedName,extensionAttribute3,extensionAttribute4,extensionAttribute2, name
                                        FROM ''''LDAP://OU=Computers,OU=' + @SiteName + ',OU=' + @Region + ',OU=Branches,DC=COMPANY,DC=COM''''
                                        WHERE objectClass = ''''Computer''''
                                        ''
                                    ) AS tblADSI

            '

            exec dbo.sp_executeSQL @SQL
```

Comment: You need to rethink this. Select every single object from AD recursively (or just all objects under your master folder), extract the container path from the distinguished name and then group by that for a count of objects by OU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this myself after thinking about it for a while.

First, I query an existing table to get a dataset of unique IDs in my org for our sites (SiteCode) and write them to a temp table with another column called 'Processed' that has the value of 0.

Then, I do a WHILE loop that has the condition of SELECT COUNT(SiteCode) FROM #TMP WHERE Processed = 0 > 1

Then I do a SELECT TOP 1 with a WHERE Processed = '0' to get a SiteCode and use that to query another table to get the LDAP path to that site's container, and then do the LDAP query for the count of Computer objects and write the value into yet another table that will hold the results I want. When I've got the data I need, I set that record to Processed = '1' and then the loop continues.

Eventually, all the sites will have Processed = '1' and the loop will finish. Then I DROP the temp table as I don't need it anymore.

I'm a bit concerned that the execution time will blow out doing it this way but apart from hand counting, I'm not sure what else to do, and I'm pretty happy with it anyway :)